# Django: File not downloading, but opening in browser

Tags: html, django, download

I have a Django model that has a file upload field in a model. I want the file to be downloaded when clicked on a webpage, However, when the button is clicked it just opens up in the browser. It seems pretty straight forward [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp), but I can't get it to work.

HTML Page

```
{% if obj.document %}
    <td><a href="{{ obj.document.url }}" download>File</td>
 {% else %}
```

Models.py

```
@property
def document_url(self):
    if self.document and hasattr(self.document, 'url'):
        return self.document.url
```

If I put the `{{ obj.document.url }}` instead of `File` I see the path to the file on AWS.

Thought?

Answer (score 0):

a `</a>` is missing after `File` but if it still doesn't work:

Depending on the file type you're trying to serve, it seems like there is no solution that works in every browser.

- You can try putting `type="application/octet-stream"` in your `<a>` tag.
- You can try adding these kind of lines in your `.htaccess` for all the file types you serve:

  ```
  AddType application/octet-stream .pdf
  ```

or

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:pdf)$">
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

- Since you're mentioning AWS, it looks like you can force a download on those filesby setting the correct headers on your files in Amazon S3.

  ```
  Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=FILENAME.EXT    
  Content-Type: application/octet-stream
  ```